# How to use unwrapped mesh on different images at different locations?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I am a beginner, and I tried searching a lot for the solution to my problem but couldn't find it. I hope you guys have been through it and understand it.

So I unwrapped my mesh, and scaled the mesh on an image texture, and it got applied, simple. Now, I want to use another image texture for the details.

But if I move my unwrapped mesh on the second image, the mesh on the first image moves too, disturbing my first image texture. I want to give a separate location and scale to my unwrapped mesh for different images, and not let the positioning of my mesh on one of the image affects its position on another.

I would be very grateful if someone can help me with this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use as many UV maps as you want, see in the Properties panel > Object Data > UV Maps. Then in the Shader Editor you can create an Input > UV Map node to use your different UV maps

Comment: Thank you so much dude, I figured I could create two UV maps, didnt realise the thing about how to tell the shader about the UV map to use. Thanks man you're a life saver!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so moonboots told me I can create a separate UV map, in Object data panel, and insert Input>UV map node to the shader editor, to specify the UV map.

Thank you so much!